# Replace column value in a data frame based on other columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame ordered by name and time.

```
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame('name' = c(rep('x', 6), rep('y', 4)), 
                 'time' = c(rep(1, 2), rep(2, 3), 3, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                 'score' = c(0, sample(1:10, 3), 0, sample(1:10, 2), 0, sample(1:10, 2))
                 )
> df
   name time score
1     x    1     0
2     x    1     4
3     x    2     3
4     x    2     5
5     x    2     0
6     x    3     1
7     y    1     5
8     y    2     0
9     y    3     5
10    y    4     8
```

In `df$score` there are zeros followed by an unknown number of actual values, i.e. `df[1:4,]`, and sometimes there are overlapping `df$name` between two `df$score == 0`, i.e. `df[6:7,]`.

I want to change `df$time` where `df$score != 0`. Specifically, I want to assign the time value of the closest upper row with `df$score == 0` if `df$name` is matching.

The following code gives the good output but my data have millions of rows so this solution is very inefficient.

```
score_0 <- append(which(df$score == 0), dim(df)[1] + 1)

for(i in 1:(length(score_0) - 1)) {
  df$time[score_0[i]:(score_0[i + 1] - 1)] <-
    ifelse(df$name[score_0[i]:(score_0[i + 1] - 1)] == df$name[score_0[i]], 
           df$time[score_0[i]], 
           df$time[score_0[i]:(score_0[i + 1] - 1)])
 }

> df
   name time score
1     x    1     0
2     x    1     4
3     x    1     3
4     x    1     5
5     x    2     0
6     x    2     1
7     y    1     5
8     y    2     0
9     y    2     5
10    y    2     8
```

Where `score_0` gives the index where `df$score == 0`. We see that `df$time[2:4]` are now all equal to 1, that in `df$time[6:7]` only the first one changed because the second have `df$name == 'y'` and the closest upper row with `df$score == 0` has `df$name == 'x'`. The last two rows also have changed correctly.

Comment: What if `df [ 7 , "time" ]` was equal to **`2`**? would it be changed to be `1` because it's the first entry of `name==y` or you would leave it unchanged?

Comment: @Masoud, You would simply leave it unchanged because the `df$name` doesn't match with the closest upper row with `df$score == 0`

Comment: Just a suggestion, when using sample or other random functions, use `set.seed` so everyone get the same output. Cheers, and welcome to the community.

Comment: @Masoud, Thanks for the `set.seed()` tip and the neat answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(ID=cumsum(score==0)) %>% 
       group_by(name,ID) %>% mutate(time = head(time,1)) %>% 
       ungroup() %>%  select(name,time,score) %>% as.data.frame()

#       name time  score
# 1     x    1     0
# 2     x    1     8
# 3     x    1    10
# 4     x    1     6
# 5     x    2     0
# 6     x    2     5
# 7     y    1     4
# 8     y    2     0
# 9     y    2     5
# 10    y    2     9
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `dplyr` and `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(
    chck = score == 0,
    chck_rl = ifelse(score == 0, lead(rleid(chck)), rleid(chck))) %>% 
  group_by(name, chck_rl) %>% mutate(time = first(time)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-chck_rl, -chck)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   name   time score
   <chr> <dbl> <int>
 1 x         1     0
 2 x         1     2
 3 x         1     9
 4 x         1     7
 5 x         2     0
 6 x         2     1
 7 y         1     8
 8 y         2     0
 9 y         2     2
10 y         2     3
```

Solution only using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, chck_rl := ifelse(score == 0, shift(rleid(score == 0), type = "lead"), 
    rleid(score == 0))][, time := first(time), by = .(name, chck_rl)][, chck_rl := NULL]
```

Output:

```
   name time score
 1:    x    1     0
 2:    x    1     2
 3:    x    1     9
 4:    x    1     7
 5:    x    2     0
 6:    x    2     1
 7:    y    1     8
 8:    y    2     0
 9:    y    2     2
10:    y    2     3
```

Comment: Consider using `cumsum`. `rleid` functions in many scenarios and is a powerful tool but is not efficient for this specific problem. Your `data.table` solution can be improved by that, however it's a good implementation already. +1

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion @Masoud. I've always prioritised `rleid` over `cumsum`, but after some benchmarking it indeed shows it may not always be the best replacement.